# Running heads with amsbook

Tags: header-footer, amsbook

I'm trying to prepare a book with chapters by many different authors, using the `amsbook` class, and the `amsbooka` package to handle the author names

The `amsbooka` class documentation claims that:

> When an author is specified for a chapter, the left-hand running head will be
> the author name; the right-hand running head will be the chapter title, taken
> from the short title.

However, this only seems to be the case if chapters aren't subdivided into sections. If they are, then the *section* title prints as the right-hand running head, instead of the chapter title. See MWE below.

Is there a simple way of modifying `amsbook / amsbooka` to always print the chapter title as the right-hand running head (and ignore any sections/subsections/etc within chapters)?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsbooka, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\author{Author}
\title{Meanderings}
\maketitle
\chapter[First Chap]{First Chapter \author{First Author}}

\lipsum[1-20] % this has the desired headings

\chapter[Second Chap]{Second Chapter \author{Second Author}}

\section{A Section} \lipsum[1-20] % section heading wipes out chapter heading!
\section{Another Section} \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect MWE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually easy (possibly an oversight in `amsbooka`).

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsbooka, lipsum}

% redefine \sectionmark so it doesn't issue a mark
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\author{Author}
\title{Meanderings}

\maketitle

\chapter[First Chap]{First Chapter\author{First Author}}

\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter[Second Chap]{Second Chapter\author{Second Author}}

\section{A Section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\section{Another Section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, contrary to what the documentation shows, there should be no space in front of `\author`.

Here's a version that simplifies the input, making the optional short title really optional.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsbooka, lipsum}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Chapter}{sO{#3}mo}{%
  % #1 = possible * for unnumbered chapter
  % #2 = optional short title (defaults to full title)
  % #3 = title
  % #4 = optional author
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% *-version
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}{% no author
      \chapter*[#2]{#3}%
    }{% author
      \chapter*[#2]{#3\author{#4}}%
    }%
  }{% numbered chapter
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}{% no author
      \chapter[#2]{#3}%
    }{% author
      \chapter[#2]{#3\author{#4}}%
    }
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\author{Author}
\title{Meanderings}

\maketitle

\Chapter*{Preface}[Author]

\lipsum[1-3]

\Chapter{First Chapter}[First Author]

\lipsum[1-20] % this has the desired headings

\Chapter[Second Chap]{Second Chapter}[Second Author]

\section{A Section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\section{Another Section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `amsbooka` was created to fill a need at AMS, and release to CTAN was an afterthought.  I'll make the suggestion to the AMS support group to consider this as an enhancement.